# Start IIS server if IIS server not running

Tags: iis

HI,

I would like to write a code in which start iss, if iis is not running.

Comment: for what language, batch files, etc?

Answer (score 7):

Starting IIS from the commandline:

```
iisreset /start
```

Stopping IIS from the commandline:

```
iisreset /stop
```

Restarting (stop and start):

```
iisreset /restart
```

Comment: I want to restart only when service is not start automaticaly 
I have found the solution 


@ECHO
net start | find /i "IISADMIN">NUL 
if errorlevel==1 net start IISADMIN
@ECHO

Comment: iisreset /start is no-op if the service is already running.  Use it with confidence!